# Class with dependency injection in AngulrJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a class which is dependent on some services but it doesn't have any view.

How to specify that class in AngularJS 1.6

If I use `@Component` then I need to mention template, but this class is pure functionality class without any view.

Also I don't want to create a service, since it will be used only once.
In following code I want to use Manager class in Main.ts

main.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  moduleName: 'APP.MAIN'
})

@View({
  bindToController: {
    input: '=',
    output: '='
  },
  template: template
})

export interface IMain {

}

export class Main implements IMain {
public manager: IManager;
 constructor(
    @Inject (
      '$q', 
      '$timeout',
      '$window')
    private $q: angular.IQService,
    private $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
    private $window: angular.IWindowService) {
    manager = new IManager();
    manager.process(3);
    }

}
```

manager.ts

```
export interface IManager {
    public process(id: number): void;

}
export class Manager implements IManager {
    constructor(
    @Inject (
      '$q', 
      '$timeout',
      '$window')
    private $q: angular.IQService,
    private $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService,
    private $window: angular.IWindowService) {

    }

    public process(id: number) : void {
        funcA();
        funcB();
        setInterval( () => this.funcC(),60000);
    }

    private funcA(): void {

    }

    private funcB(): void {

    }

    private funcC(): void {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add the code you already have. We're no fortune tellers. ;)

Comment: what do you plan on doing with your class? DOM manipulations - use a directive. Running common functions without the view - use services / factories / providers.

Comment: @Aleksey Thanks ..I want to write some functions  and those will use some services. But those functions are not common

Comment: @spidyspidy can you give an example of such functions and how they will be used? Otherwise just use a service and inject it into another service.

Comment: No I dont want to create a service...since this is not a common functionality..I was thinking of creating a simple class but since I need some other services also(using dependeny injection) ...so I am not able to find a way to that..

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are looking for some _solution_, while not describing the _problem_. Once again, **what** are you trying to do with your class? How is it used?

Comment: @aleksey I have updated the sample code.